# How to place an aspx page inside update panel of another aspx page

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

Is it possible to place an aspx page inside the update panel of another aspx page? If so, how can I do that?

Comment: The other page is controlled by you ? Iframe ?

Comment: The other page is taken care by me only, its not an IFrame. Its normal aspx page.

Comment: UserControl instead of a Page?

Comment: The page is already developed and I need to integrate the code with the existing aspx page. I can do integrating by copying all  the controls to the main aspx page but I want to add the page directly to the existing aspx page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try out UFrame (Update Panel + IFrame), have a look at http://uframe.codeplex.com/

You can put the UFrame in your main.aspx, and specify the src property to your existing aspx page, as below:

In mainpage.aspx:

```
<div class="UFrame" id="UFrame1" src="ExistingPage.aspx" >
  <p>This should get replaced with content from Existingpage.aspx</p>
</div>
```